# Não consigo resolver ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express.js, servidor

Meu programa aponta ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT que pelo o que eu entendi, ocorre quando uma resposta já foi enviada pelo servidor. Eu estou tentando criar um método do controlador de uma rota que muda algumas informações do usuário. Para isso eu fiz dois outros métodos do mesmo controlador, um que carrega o usuário e o outro autentica. Esses dois métodos vêm antes do método que muda as informações do usuário, nessa ordem: carrega -> autentica -> altera. Eu não vejo da onde vem o ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT, já que ele aponta na única linha onde uma reposta é enviada. Não tenho muita experiência com express. Aqui está o código:

```
controller.loadUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await database.sync();
    
    let userId = req.body.data.id;
    
    const user = await User.findByPk(userId);
    
    req.user = user;
  }
  
  catch (error) {
    req.error = error;
  }
  
  finally {
    next();
  }
};

controller.authenticateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.error !== undefined)
    next();
  
  try {
    await database.sync();
    
    let {login: authLogin, password: authPassword} = req.body.data.authentication;
    let {login, password} = req.user;
    
    if (login === authLogin && password === authPassword)
      next();
    
    let error = new Error("User authentication failed.");
    error.name = "UserAuthenticationError";
    
    throw error;
  }
  
  catch (error) {
    req.error = error;
  }
  
  finally {
    next();
  }
};

controller.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.error !== undefined)
    next(req.error);
  
  var user = req.user;
  
  try {
    await database.sync();
    
    let newData = req.body.data.update;
    
    for (let attribute of Object.keys(newData))
      user[attribute] = newData[attribute];
    
    user.save({
      "fields": [
        "username", "login", "password"
      ]
    });
    
    // Aqui é onde o error é apontado.
    res.json({
      "data": user
    });
  }
  
  catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }

};
```

Aqui está o erro:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:370:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:573:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/moccot/NetBeansProjects/secoar/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/moccot/NetBeansProjects/secoar/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/moccot/NetBeansProjects/secoar/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at controller.updateUser (/home/moccot/NetBeansProjects/secoar/src/api/controller/users.js:137:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

A chamada da função `next` não termina a execução da função atual.

Repare que na função `authenticateUser` você tem duas chamadas para função `next`, uma se a condição `req.error !== undefined` for verdadeira, e a outra se no seu `finally`.

O que acontece se a condição `req.error !== undefined` for verdadeira, é que o `next` será invocado, fazendo com que o próximo middleware/rota seja executado, no caso, o `updateUser`, mas depois que a função `updateUser` terminar de rodar (na verdade ele não vai esperar terminar, pois é assíncrono), a função `authenticateUser` volta a rodar, chamando o `next` novamente, e portanto executando o `updateUser` novamente.

Como o `updateUser` é executado duas vezes, o `res.json({ "data": user })` é invocado duas vezes. Na primeira vez não dá problema, na segunda ele falha, pois você já enviou a resposta.

Para terminar a função `authenticateUser`, e impedir que ela continue rodando após o `next`, utilize um `return`:

```
controller.authenticateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.error !== undefined) {
    return next();
  }

  // resto do código
};
```